# How do I get average rating and round up to nearest 1?

Tags: php, sql, average

I have a voting table called `product_reviews`, with a field that is `ENUM` from 1 to 5 called `rating`.

I want to get average rating from all rows with product_id 1665. I am using a star rating system so the average cannot be with decimals. Must be a number from 1 to 5.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Why are you using an enum field type rather than int field type?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I was just worried that someone might attempt to post to my form using a number other than 1 to 5. ENUM restricts that I believe. But I am a beginner so I might not be doing this right.

Comment: Simply check that the posted value is <= 5 when your are processing the form data. Your validation should happen *before* you include the data in a SQL query.

Comment: Ok great. Good to have another set of eyes. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT round(avg(rating)) as average_review, 
       count(rating) as number_of_reviews
FROM product_reviews 
WHERE product_id = 1665
```

You need to use `round` here since `avg` will return a value between 1.0 and 5.0, and if you use `floor` or `ceil` you're effectively eliminating 1 *or* 5 from the possible results unless *all* reviews on the product have that score.

Also, you'll alienate your users if they can openly see a product got 50 reviews with 1 star, and 1 review with 2 stars, and you're showing an average score of 2 stars next to that. It'll make your site seem unreliable which is usually not a good thing for a site that contains reviews. For this reason most star rating systems are also capable of showing partial stars to make it more precise.

Comment: That was fast. thank you! Works great! Any idea how to count the number of reviews available for  product_id?

Comment: `ROUND()` will round down if the fraction is less than .5, use [`CEIL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil) to always round up.

Comment: Thank  you Sammitch. Yes, I want to round up.

Comment: No you don't want to round up, if you do that the resulting average will never state `1` unless there are **only** reviews with 1 star. It is inherent to this type of rating systems that rounding to the extremes always happens less often than those in between. I also updated the query to count the number of reviews as well.